Which is more soluble in water - Butan-1-ol or Butan-1amine?
While studying about the physical properties of amines, I came across a question -

Which is more soluble in water butan-1-ol or butan-1-amine?

If I think that butan-1-ol is more soluble in water, I could justify by saying that since it has a higher polarity (having more electronegative Oxygen).
But on the other hand, isn't it also true that butan-1-amine will be more associated to the water molecules due to presence of 2 H available for H- bonding with water, unlike butan-1-ol which has only 1 H for H bonding. I believe the extent of intermolecular association in Butan-1-amine is higher.
I tried finding the solubility of both online and found this article on butan-1-ol which states it's solubility is 7.7 g/100mL
Whereas for butan-1-amine this article states that it is miscible in water.
I want to know which of the will truly have a higher solubility in water, their solubility values (if possible) and the reason.
Thank you.

I think you found your answer: miscibility is when two liquids fully dissolve with each other in all proportions. It is the basicity of the amine which makes it more soluble.

@Sonder Im pretty sure butan-1-ol is more soluble than butan-1-amine.

@Piyush The Handbook of Chemistry and Physics says 1-butanol is soluble in water, while butylamine is miscible with water.

In this context don't miscibility and solubility mean the same? I dont really understand the difference

I'm not really sure abt the difference
